# Combi Drill causing battery failure

Tags: tool-repair, drill

First of all apologies if this is the wrong forum, not sure where else I can ask this question, but I have a Makita DHP482 Combi drill, and it seems to be killing all new batteries I use with it. Brand new batteries, fully charged run for maybe 5 seconds, and then smoke from the battery itself. Then the battery will no longer charge.
Any Ideas?

Comment: have you tried contacting Makita?  that is where I would start.

Comment: There's a short or something inside and, well, you know the phrase "no user-serviceable parts inside"? Well it applies for sure to modern cordless drills. I think contacting the manufacturer should be your #1 option, although I wouldn't hold out much hope of them providing a satisfactory resolution if it's no longer in warranty (and even then maybe not). BTW, you say batter**ies**..... how many has this killed? I'd have stopped trying after the second one for sure, maybe even the first given the [true] horror stories of Li-Ion batteries catching fire!

Comment: I wouldn't buy into the "no user-serviceable parts inside" caution. I've repaired a couple of cordless DeWalt drills and circular saws and my corded miter saw. If it's out of warranty, open that sucker up and see what's going on inside! Odds are _really_ good that you'll see some burnt wiring or at least melted insulation. If you're good with a soldering iron, you can try repairing wiring, or, purchase repair parts online. Unfortunately, though, tool repair _is_ off-topic here.

Comment: @FreeMan, my point was about this voiding the warranty since contacting the manufacturer should be the first port of call. Within warranty the user is behind the 8 ball as there's no way they can even discover what an internal fault might be without it being voided :-\ Although to be fair, given the potential for people to monkey around inside or make silly mistakes I can't really fault them for this position.

Comment: I have contacted them, they need to have it sent and checked by their own repair team, and will give me a quote on repair. It is out of warranty, hence why I was hoping for a diy fix. I will open it up as suggested and try and find any visible problems as mentioned.

Comment: Probably a better fit for DIY.SE.

Comment: Since it is out of warranty you lose nothing by opening it up and looking for anything like @FreeMan mentions. BTW I can virtually guarantee that any repair quote you get from a an authorised repair centre will exceed the value of the drill :-( Given supply-chain issues due to Covid the problem is likely worse than it ever was before, but *individual components* can often come close to — possibly even exceed — the price of a brand new drill. [This isn't because these parts *actually* cost that much, it's just that they're either priced that way deliberately, or demand drives the price higher.]

Comment: I would agree with @Graphus on repair center pricing. I brought a drill into an authorized drop off point (they don't repair, just ship to the place that does). The quote for an _inspection_ was almost the same price as buying a new drill. I disagree, though, on repair part cost. I ended up buying a couple of replacement parts simply to make the part cost higher than the shipping cost. After an hour of fiddly work, I got my drill working again and I had a 2nd spare part. Of course, _some_ parts will be close to the cost of a whole new tool...

Comment: @FreeMan, sorry to keep on coming back with clarifications but I meant the price of the spare parts *through them*. In addition of course their labour/time costs are often exorbitantly high (again quite deliberately, to discourage out-of-warranty repairs).

Comment: Are the batteries still under warranty?

Comment: Are batteries _ever_ truly under warranty? Most companies treat them as "consumables". You might be able to make a case if they failed out of the packaging but expect push-back. They can't, or won't, trust that they were used or charged in a safe manner from day 0. (Yes, I know Makita claim a 3-year warranty on batteries. I'm just wondering how that claim would ever work out in real life, considering the "normal wear-and-tear" clause.)

Comment: @jdv — I’m not on the Makita platform, but I’ve personally gotten a replacement flexvolt battery (as have co-workers) from Dewalt. They have a 3 year warranty, either from manufacture date or receipt of purchase. (Parenthetically, I’ve found Dewalt really strong on warranty support.)